# Tikz surface should conceal markers

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to recreate a plot I originally did in Matlab.
It is an opaque surface with additionally plotted lines including markers.

The matlab picture I want to recreate with a concealed and unconcealed marker:

[image]

Some of these markers are "below" and some "above" the surface from the viewpoint. I also want this difference to be visible in Latex, but I dont know how. I tried with different layers "clip mode=individual", but then all points were concealed.

The surface in latex:

[image]

The surface in latex with clip mode = individual:

[image]

I know it is a slight different data set than in Matlab, but with view={0}{0}, I can verify that some points should be above and some below the surface aswell.

Hopefully my question is understandable and would be thankful, if someone could help.

I tried with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height = 10cm,
            width = 0.8\textwidth,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line*=left,
            view={20}{20},
   clip mode=individual,
            grid=both]
  
  \addplot3+[]table[x=y1, y=x, z=z1 ]{data/TsurfLines.txt};
  \addlegendentry{Row 1}
  \addplot3+[]table[x=y2, y=x, z=z2 ]{data/TsurfLines.txt};
  \addlegendentry{Row 2}
  \addplot3+[]table[x=y3, y=x, z=z3 ]{data/TsurfLines.txt};
  \addlegendentry{Row 3}
  \addplot3+[]table[x=y4, y=x, z=z4 ]{data/TsurfLines.txt};
  \addlegendentry{Row 4}
  \addplot3+[]table[x=y5, y=x, z=z5 ]{data/TsurfLines.txt};
  \addlegendentry{Row 5}
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.7] file {data/Tsurf.txt};
  \addlegendentry{Model}
  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal working example. We neither know what packages etc. you use nor can we reproduce your image because we don't have access to the data.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PGFPlots does not have a z buffer extending outside of the individual plots, so what you want can not be done without manual work. You can pick the points yourself or if you have a threshold number or formula, you can use a filter like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={20}{20},
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
clip mode=individual,
]
\addplot3[
only marks, domain=0.01:1, samples=10, samples y=1, 
z filter/.expression={0.2+0.1*sin(1000*y)<0.2?z:nan},
] (0.5,x,{0.2+0.1*sin(1000*x)});
\addplot3[surf, shader=interp, opacity=0.8, domain=0.01:1, samples=100, samples y=2] (x,y,{(x-1)^2-0.01/x});
\addplot3[
only marks, domain=0.01:1, samples=10, samples y=1, 
z filter/.expression={0.2+0.1*sin(1000*y)>0.2?z:nan},
] (0.5,x,{0.2+0.1*sin(1000*x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Transparent surface plots with points below and above]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the solution. I am sorry I havent provided a minimum working example yet- I was just working on it! But I think this answer helps me already